# Component to dynamically Reshuffle the table contents in Adf

Tags: oracle-adf

Is there any ADF Component that will let me to dynamically reshuffle the records in a table?
That is, if there are 50 records in a table and I want to re-order the first record with 20th record in a user interface way?
That is, 20th record will be displayed in the top order followed by the first record.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box feature, but you can do this by retrieving the iterator behind this table, and start messing around with the rows and do whatever you want, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEswwpwwhoI) and [this](http://techiecook.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/programmatically-populate-view-objects-in-oracle-adf/) can be helpful to show you a way to do it.